# Get The Table Name Of Model In T4 Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, t4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using MVC4 ,T4 Scaffolding  and EF5. 
I Created a model,

```
namespace wbtest.Models
{
[Table(name: "Pay_Employees_Mst", Schema = "Test")]
public class Employee
 {
public int EMPLOYEE_ID { get; set; }
public string EMPLOYEE_CODE { get; set; }
}
}
```

I need to get the annotation of table name "Pay_Employees_Mst" for db context .Currently getting ModelName Employee.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it through,

```
String entityName1 = (context as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
  .CreateObjectSet<Employee>()
  .EntitySet.Name;
```